# Перезаписать одного из предков для коммита слияния

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

### Что есть:

Есть ветка **C** в которую вмержены ветки **А** и **В**.

```
* 113cfa6 (HEAD -> master) 12
* 74f6351 10
| *   f63d30b (C) Merge branch 'B' into C
| |\
| | * afe44c6 (B) 8
| | * 1da5826 7
| * | 3b5fa89 11
| * |   93d7b1d Merge branch 'A' into C
| |\ \
|/ / /
| * | 9023742 (A) 3
| * | 8e7ac5c 2
* | | eb15793 (X) 9
| |/
|/|
* | 01ea56d 6
* | 11585f1 5
* | c8905ca 4
|/
* dc6c154 1
```

### Что нужно:

Нужно перемотать ветку **С** на последний комит **мастера**.

```
*   6099fa1 (C) Merge branch 'B' into C
|\
| * afe44c6 (B) 8
| * 1da5826 7
* | b8a7ffd 11
* |   7f48be6 Merge branch 'A' into C
|\ \
| * | 9023742 (A) 3
| * | 8e7ac5c 2
* | | 113cfa6 (HEAD -> master) 12
* | | 74f6351 10
* | | eb15793 (X) 9
| |/
|/|
* | 01ea56d 6
* | 11585f1 5
* | c8905ca 4
|/
* dc6c154 1
```

### Что пробовал:

`git rebase master C` Но это убивает все мердж комиты и ребейзит все комиты веток **А** и **В** на **мастер**.

### История:

Объясню откуда появились такие странные требования. `master` используется для получения актуальных данных из remoute, все поставки в него через pullrequest. Каждая отдельная ветка (А,В) это решения для определенного issue. В конце какого то периода создается ветка `pr`(С) в которую вмердживают несколько бранчей(А,В), создают pullrequest и запускают тесты. Тесты как всегда падают, и фиксы по возможности поставляют в те бранчи(А,В) которые вмерджены в `pr`(С). Но иногда возникают конфликты или фиксы невозможно добавить в бранчи(А,В), так появляются отдельные комиты (11) в ветке `pr`(С). Пока проходят фиксы ветка `master` уже убегает вперед и нужно подмержить изменения в ветку `pr`(C). Мерджи из мастера происходят так часто что в ветке `pr`(C) половина коммитов это подливка мастера, потом pullrequest принимается и мастер превращается в паутину "подливок из мастера". Появилась идея избежать ненужных мерджей с мастером, и было принято решение перематывать ветку `pr`(С) от последнего комита `master` вместо мерджа с ним.

Comment: А в чём проблема установить ветку `C` = `master` и смёржить туда `A` и `B`?

Comment: В ветке С может быть запутанная история из мерджей и отедльных комитов. Вариант С = master подразумеват, полностью повторить всю историю которая была сделана в ветке С. Это занаво решить конфликты, найти только мердж комиты и черипикнуть отдельные комиты. Я щас так и делаю, но подозреваю что можно проще.

Comment: Из того, что вы описали в вопросе, не видно ни мёржей, ни собственных коммитов в ветке `C`. Опишите в вопросе ситуацию, более похожую на реальную, покажите все сложности (не обязательно с хешами коммитов). Были ли в `C` мёржи из `master`, ещё откуда-то?

Comment: Обновил карты, теперь видно что в `С` присуствуют два мерджа (A и B) и отдельный комит (11) между мерджами. В `C` нельзя мерджить `master`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужна опция `-p` (`--preserve-merges`), она заставляет `rebase` не развёртывать мёржи, а сохранять их. На заметку: не рекомендуется эту опцию использовать вместе с `-i` (`--interactive`), а если уж использовать, то не переупорядочивать коммиты, иначе результат может быть неожиданным.

```
git rebase -p master C
```

Comment: выявилась проблема, если ветку А изменить, например добавить комит, то команда `git reabase -p master C` перебазирует только часть ветки С. Тоесть перебазированная ветка С не будет содержать актуальний комит из ветки А. Похоже на то что при перебазировании применяеться команда мерджа с указанными точными комитами а не с именными бранчами.

Comment: @duhon Под "ветку А изменить, например добавить комит" вы подразумеваете добавить в ветку `A` коммит после того, как она вмёржена в `C`?

Comment: да. А потом перебазировать ветку `С` c учетом изменной ветки `А`. Тоесть просто `git rebase -p master C`

Comment: @duhon Погодите, а вы делаете мёрж изменённой ветки `A` в `C` перед тем, как ребейзить `C`?

Comment: @master да делалал, состояние из вопроса "Что есть", тоесть ветка `С` имете последний комит f63d30b в которой присуствуте 93d7b1d (мердж с А).

Comment: @duhon Тогда должно работать. Только я не понимаю, чем такая ситуация принципиально отличается от изначально описанной в вопросе.